# Connect to Oracle database from Xamarin cross platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

It is showing error when open the connection(oracle connection is not opening)

Error
**Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: occurred**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide more info for your problem. How do you connect to the DB? What nuget package/approach are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Don't connect to DB directly from a mobile device, that's not a good approach. I think it cant be done either because this DLL is not even available for mobile platforms.

Get the data from the database via REST services through a server. Check this article [how to consume REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest)  in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 1):

Android and iOS apps do not have the ability to connect to a database outside of their own SQLite databases.

In order for a mobile app to get data from an Oracle database, one needs to create a REST backend with any popular framework (eg. ASP.NET, Express.js, Ruby on Rails, Django), then the app can communicate with this service.